# Private YouTube video, accessible to everyone with a Google account

Tags: youtube, privacy, security, sharing, access-control

Is there a way to create a private video on YouTube, that is marked private but with access granted to everyone with a Google account? When creating a private video, it's possible to mark which accounts will have access. I'd like a private video where all Google accounts have access.

---

The motivation: I want to report a bug in an open-source tool. It works correctly with public videos, but incorrectly with private videos. I want to give the developers a specific example of a private video that they can use to reproduce the bug. However, if I create my own private video that's visible only to me, the developers won't be able to access it. And since it's open-source, there could be any number of developers. Thus, I'd like to have a video that YouTube treats as a private video, but that any developer anywhere in the world with a Google account can access if they log into their Google account. If they try to view it without logging in, they won't be able to view the video; but if they log into their own Google account, they should be able to view it.

Is it possible to create such a video on YouTube?  Does one already exist?

Comment: You could make the video _unlisted_, thus giving access to it to anybody who has the direct link.

Comment: you can create private community group and invite ppl via link - eg. only ppl with link and with acc can access it

Answer (score 1):

YouTube does not support this kind of thing, you need to specify which email addresses exactly should have access.

As a workaround, you can record a screen capture of you performing the steps to reproduce yourself and upload those as a public video.